# GestureListener Interfering with ClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener, gesture

I had a perfectly good ClickListener code that worked perfectly until I added

```
gestureObject = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new LearnGesture());
```

and

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d("OkHttp","Goody");

        this.gestureObject.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    class LearnGesture extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override

        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float veloclityX, float velocityY) {
            Log.d("OkHttp","Goody");
            String url = "";
            String url22 = "";
            if (event2.getX() > event1.getX()) {



            } else if (event2.getX() < event1.getX()) {


            }

            return true;
        }


    }
```

For a "Swipe Listener".

The swipe function works fine but now my ClickListener will not work.

Any Ideas why?
Do they interfere with each other?

Comment: why dont you call `super.dispatchTouchEvent` when you override `dispatchTouchEvent` method?

Answer (score 0):

retrning true means you are consuming the event, so return it true only when you have detected a gesture in your case and for all other events return false so that default funtion will work.
Please refer to https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html#DetectingAllSupportedGestures